# Prove that a square number doesn't end in 2 odd digits.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I have heard of this result on MSE and I'm interested if anyone can prove it. The shortest answer will be ticked.
The only proof I found was tedious. It went writing squares in the form $100x+ab$ where $a$ &$b$ are odd numbers

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? If so,  are you stuck etc.? Or is this being laid out as a challenge?

Comment: $a^2\not\equiv3\pmod4$

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг I have posted my working below.

Comment: @lordsharktheunknown I don't understand.

Comment: "The only proof I found was tedious. It went writing squares in the form $100x+ab$ where $a$ &$b$ are odd numbers." That's basically the simplest way to do it, as far as I know.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown that only shows half of the odd numbers can't be squares.  There are numbers which end in two odd digits which are $1\pmod{4}$ and there are squares which are $1\pmod{4}$.  Your comment does not suggest why these two sets cannot overlap.

Comment: @Arthur I'm only 16. I wanted a short little proof.

Comment: @PintOfMilk Some times proofs just can't be made short and little. That being said, if anyone has a more elegant way to prove it, I'd be really interested to see it. I just wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: That being said, the same technique that proves that $a^2\not\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ can be used to show for example why every square ends in either $0,1,4,5,6,9$ (*in their decimal representation*) and that no square can end in $2,3,7$ or $8$.  The same technique can be used for finding all of the possible ways that the final two digits can appear.  It is tedious, but it is simple enough that anyone should be able to understand.

Comment: Some shortcuts can be taken... for example using the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  We know that a square number must be $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$ and it cannot be $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$.  We can also learn that a square number must be either $0,1$ or $4$ modulo $5$ and that it cannot be $2$ or $3$ modulo $5$.  This information combined via the chinese remainder theorem will tell us what the possibilities are modulo $20$, and we will learn that $11,13,15,17,19,\dots$ are all impossible results modulo $20$ thus implying the result modulo $100$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Or we can just check $1^2,3^2,5^2,7^2$ and $9^2$ modulo $20$, and conclude directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number to be squared be $10t+u$.  Then we have:
$$(10t+u)^2=100t^2+20tu+u^2$$
It is easy to see that the first term is irrelevant.  The second term maintains an even tens digit, so it can also be ignored.  Now, we are left with $u^2$ and for $(10t+u)^2$ to be odd, $u$ must be odd.  Looking at the odd unit squares, we have
 { $1, 9, 25, 49, 81$ } of which all have even (or no -- zero) tens digits.  Since none will change the evenness of the tens digit, we can conclude no integer squared can end in two odd digits.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the expressions $(10x+1)^2$ , $(10x+3)^2$ , $(10x+5)^2$ , $(10x+7)^2$ and $(10x+9)^2$ and show that each of them leads to a number of the form $20k+1$ , $20k+5$ or $20k+9$

With PARI/GP , this can be done easily :

```
? forstep(j=1,9,2,print(j,"  ",lift(Mod((10*k+j)^2,100))))
1  20*k + 1
3  60*k + 9
5  25
7  40*k + 49
9  80*k + 81
?
```

Answer (score 0):

$(10n+u)^2\bmod20=u^2\bmod20=ee,eo,ee,eo,oe,eo,oe,eo,ee$ or $eo$.

Comment: For example $12345^2\bmod20=5^2\bmod20=05$, even/odd. The $\bmod20$ operation preserves the parities of the last two digits.